# Distorted custom Navigation buttons on non-retina display (using stretchable image method)

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, uinavigationbar, retina-display

I am adding custom navigation buttons to my navigation bars via the following code.

```
//Instance method in CustomNavButton Class

-(UIButton*)setupButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)image andFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame]autorelease];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.size.width-20)/2, (frame.size.height-20)/2, 20, 20)];
    imageView.image = image;

    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customBtn_black"];
    UIImage *stretchableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal
                                         stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];

    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [button setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImageNormal
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addSubview:imageView];

    return button;

}

//Call CustomNavButton and add to Navbar
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Add left invite friends button 
    CustomNavButton *leftButton = [[CustomNavButton alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_1"] andFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 32)];
    [leftButton.customNavButton addTarget:self action:@selector(inviteButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:leftButton];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
    [leftButton release];

}
```

The navigation buttons appear fine on my iPhone (IOS5 with Retina Display)

[image]

However, the buttons look distorted on my simulator (or non-retina display)

[image]

How can I resolve this? How can I display the buttons properly even for non-retina displays?

Note that I have created the @2x buttons for this as well

[image]

EDIT:

It seems like the issue likes with the stretching of the image

```
UIImage *stretchableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal
                                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
```

If I change the leftCapWidth value to 0, the buttons on the simulator looks better (but still bad).

[image]

But by doing this, it will cause my retina display button look a little distorted (seems like I can't win).

Can anyone advise if the problem does really lie here, and how I can alter the values so that it works well for both retina and non-retina displays?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have two files? MyImage.png and MyImage@2x.png? It looks like the system is trying to resize the @2x file by scaling it down, which usually causes some jaggedness like this when it is simply scaled down.

MyImage.png should be half the size of MyImage@2x.png.

Comment: I am using a base image and stretching it using UIImage *stretchableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal
                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0]; That stretching part seemed to be the one causing the issue, but am not sure how to resolve it

Comment: yup it does seem like the number of pixels I select with the left cap width causes the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your not setting the file format .png or whatever it is you have. And as Chris said you need two files regular and @2x.